# Installing latest Visual Studio to Windows 7 - Setup exits with no errors or warnings

Tags: c++, visual-studio, installation

I have been forced to work on an  online compiler (http://cpp.sh/). Yikes... But, still, it is something!

It is a bit difficult to get windows 10 because of all the programs I will have to reinstall. I know it is a long shot - I was hoping someone might have had the same problem here and knows the solution.

What happens is I download the proper file from the official site. As soon as I execute it (as admin), a window pops up showing that something is loading and some files are being created at programfiles(x 86)\Microsoft Visual Studio. After that it exits with no errors/warnings. If I execute again the same loading screen appears but the loading seems to be at 100% from the start (presumably because the files have already been created?). After 5 to 10 seconds the same happens - setup exits with no errors/warnings.

If anyone has any idea what is going on.. well help me? I found a ton of incidents about windows 7 installation problems but none without error messages

Comment: I don't want to be rude but using an 11 years old os that's not even receiving support anymore just to avoid the reinstallation of some programs sounds like a really bad idea. In the time youre investing here trying to get new software to run on it you probably would have been already half way done migrating to Windows 10. Are you sure the latest version VS2019 even properly supports Windows 7?

Comment: What version of VS you try to install ? Check your `.NET` version or just run `Windows update` may be you have a old .NET version

Comment: I was installing 2019. No, I actually would not be half way done and VS 2019 supports Win7. I also kind of dislike win10 that another half reason I guess.. I would be giving linux a but half the programs I need don't support linux.

Comment: @Windfish You can upgrade Windows 7 to Windows 10 through an update without doing a reinstall. You probably won't have to reinstall any of your applications in the process. It should not take longer than maybe an hour.

Comment: I also need to change system drive to an SSD (using an HDD now). Do you think that would be possible with an upgrade?

Comment: You would probably replace your system drive separately, before or after you do the upgrade. As for installing VS on Windows 7, that's not really a programming question and we probably can't help you with the amount of information that we have anyway.

Comment: I have not tried the solutions yet but I will update this post with my results as soon as I do.

Answer (score 1):

> Installing latest Visual Studio to Windows 7 - Setup exits with no
>   errors or warnings

It is quite abnormal and please try these steps：

1) run cmd as administrator and then type: `net stop winmgmt`

2) Open a Windows Explorer and locate the path to `C:\windows\system32\WBEM\` folder and rename the `Repository` folder to something else like `RepositoryOLD`.

3) run cmd as administrator and then run `winmgmt /resetRepository`.

4) completely deleting the entire `VisualStudio` folder from the registry --> `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/VisualStudio`

5) then restart PC and test again.

6) If there are any OS updates or any Windows 7 patches, please install them in case there are some fixes.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: I followed your steps and got the same behavior as before. Now I think I should mention that I have an installation of Atmel Studio on my system. Could this be the root o the problem? As far as I know Atmel Studio is a Visual Studio in disguise. Could there be a conflict in trying to install both?

Comment: Please check whether you have Installer folder under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer` and if so, I suggest you could run `vs_installershell.exe` as administrator and then select `Available` to choose the related one to install. Besides, sorry for that I am not familiar with Atmel Studio. Perhaps it could be a factor. You could try it: Uninstall it and then install the vs_installer.

Comment: Imma get a copy of Win 10 :/ It is about time probably. Nothing worked